# htaccess multiple parameter virtual subdomain redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, parameters, subdomain

I am currently working on a project, what i want to achieve is to be able to pass multiple parameters to page and redirect ( one parameter as a sub-domain).
also i have to do this for multiple added hosts so i don't have a specific domain name and have to use [^.] for domain names.

for example :
boss.domain.com/topics --> [www.domian.com/topics.php?username=boss](http://www.domian.com/topics.php?username=boss)
I've read lots of solutions, but none did the trick :|

======
for the record, this what I'm using for redirection right now:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ws)\.[^.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ws\.domain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^ domain.com/ws%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

======

would appreciate if you could help me out here.
regards.

Answer (score 0):

**Put this rule before other rules:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ws)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1?username=%1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```